Problem in contract deployment in testnet using hardhat
I am trying to deploy my smart contract in the bnb testnet in the deploy script, this is my deploy script:
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const artifacts = require('../artifacts/contracts/BigBang_LendingService.sol/BigBang_LendingService.json');

async function main() {
    const web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/');
    const privateKey = '0f3....e18';

    const deployer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
    console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

    const bigbangLendingSystemContract = new web3.eth.Contract(artifacts.abi);
    const rawContract = bigbangLendingSystemContract.deploy({
        data: artifacts.bytecode,
        arguments: [
            '0xd0D5e3DB44DE05E9F294BB0a3bEEaF030DE24Ada', // networkCoinPriceFeed
            38, // ownerFeePercent
            web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'), // voteFee
            90, // lendingLimitationPercent
            web3.utils.toWei('800', 'ether'), // lowestPrice
            web3.utils.toWei('1000', 'ether'), // highestPrice
            30, // repaymentPeriod
            web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether') // ownerShare
        ]
    });

    try {
        const bigbangLendingSystem = await rawContract.send({
            from: deployer.address,
            gas: 5000000,
            gasPrice: "10000000000"
        });

        console.log('Contract deployed to: ' + bigbangLendingSystem.options.address);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error deploying contract:', error);
    }
}

main().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});



When I run this script using the command npx hardhat run .\scripts\deploy.js
I get this error even though the private key is completely correct:

InvalidPrivateKeyError: Invalid Private Key, Not a valid string or uint8Array

I am using hardhat for smart contract testing environment, can you help me to solve the problem?
Thanks a lot

Add 0x as prefix to your private key, like:
const privateKey = '0x0f3....e18';

NOTE: Never use your private key as plain text anywhere. Always use it in encrypted format using packages like env-enc, etc.

Thank you so much

You're welcome. Happy coding!
